# How to compile and run existing project of scala in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt

How to configure and run existing project of scala in eclipse using sbt? how to use build.sbt? how to configure sbt in eclipse? or how to run  **sbt run** in eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sbt pluging for generate eclipse project:

https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse